# ColdFusion : CoinBase API : CB-ACCESS-SIGN ERROR

Tags: coldfusion, base64, hmac, coinbase-api, coldfusion-2016

I am almost there for getting the CoinBase API Sorted - but missing something or a bad conversion. I have tried a few things. This is best I can get too for building everything.  I even setup a brand new key, in case old key.

I get a response from CoinBase : {"message":"invalid signature"}
If I purposely error out Key, Passphrase, Timestampe : it identifies those as incorrect.  So all is right except this signature bit.  I've included the Coinbase API Signature Details as well.

```
 <cfset base_api = "https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/orders">
 <cfset req_path = "/orders">

 <cfset cb_key = "9999ac99999e6e99ee10dfd8ea5f9999">
 <cfset cb_s = "999a7S/JZVX09EAX/LvWz9999/ALnVQptso999999dxrVfXfd999993OXAlfdPGwGZUKPBa99999pg1ubhVlsw==">

 <cfset cb_pass = "999957agr99">

 <cfset pair = "SHIB-USDT">
 <cfset side = "sell">
 <cfset type = "market">
 <cfset size = "79940">

 <cfset startDate = createdatetime( '1970','01','01','00','00','00' )> 
 <cfset datetimeNow = dateConvert( "local2Utc", now() )>
 <cfset gmtnow = #DateAdd("h", 7, datetimeNow)#>
 <cfset UnixStamp = datediff( 's', startdate, gmtnow )>

 <cfscript>
     cbs = #cb_s#;
     body = SerializeJSON({
     size: '#size#',
     type: '#type#',
     side: '#side#',
     product_id: '#pair#'});
     method = 'POST';

     // create the prehash string by concatenating required parts
     message = #UnixStamp# & method & #req_path# & body;

     // decode the base64 secret
     key = toBinary( #cb_s# );

     // create sha256 hmac with the key
     theHmac = hmac("#message#","#Key#", "HMACSHA256");
    
     // encode the result
     cas = toBase64(theHmac);

 </cfscript>
     
 <cfoutput>

 <br>#cbs#<br>

 <b>#cas#</b><br><br>
 <br>#message#

 </cfoutput> 


 <cfhttp url="#base_api#" method="post" result="result" charset="utf-8"> 
 <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="product_id" value="#pair#"> 
 <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="side" value="#side#"> 
 <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="type" value="#type#"> 
 <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="size" value="#size#">

 <cfhttpparam type="header" name="CB-ACCESS-KEY" value="#cb_key#"> 
 <cfhttpparam type="header" name="CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE" value="#cb_pass#"> 
 <cfhttpparam type="header" name="CB-ACCESS-SIGN" value="#cas#"> 
 <cfhttpparam type="header" name="CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP" value="#unixstamp#"> 

 </cfhttp>
```

This is from COINBASE API Documentation

Signing a Message

The CB-ACCESS-SIGN header is generated by creating a sha256 HMAC using the base64-decoded secret key on the prehash string timestamp + method + requestPath + body (where + represents string concatenation) and base64-encode the output. The timestamp value is the same as the CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP header.

The body is the request body string or omitted if there is no request body (typically for GET requests).

The method should be UPPER CASE.

Remember to first base64-decode the alphanumeric secret string (resulting in 64 bytes) before using it as the key for HMAC. Also, base64-encode the digest output before sending in the header.

```
 var crypto = require('crypto');

 var cb_access_timestamp = Date.now() / 1000; // in ms
 var cb_access_passphrase = '...';
 var secret = 'PYPd1Hv4J6/7x...';
 var requestPath = '/orders';
 var body = JSON.stringify({
     price: '1.0',
     size: '1.0',
     side: 'buy',
     product_id: 'BTC-USD'
 });
 var method = 'POST';

 // create the prehash string by concatenating required parts
 var message = cb_access_timestamp + method + requestPath + body;

 // decode the base64 secret
 var key = Buffer(secret, 'base64');

 // create a sha256 hmac with the secret
 var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key);

 // sign the require message with the hmac
 // and finally base64 encode the result
 var cb_access_sign = hmac.update(message).digest('base64');
```

Comment: Couple things stand out **(1)** The code is still using the wrong value for `UnixStamp`. See the example in your other thread **(2)** The parameters should be sent as the request body (formatted as JSON) not as separate `formfield`s. **(3)** Always assume API's are case sensitive.  Your JSON code will produce all *upper* case keys `{ "SIZE": "1.0"}` instead of `{ "size": "1.0"}` .  To preserve the correct case, wrap all key names in quotes i.e. `SerializeJSON({ "size": "#size#", ....})`.

Comment: 1) The UnixStamp in the cfhttpparam is correct - it errors other wise and I can compare that to the https://www.epochconverter.com/ : 2 and 3) are you saying I should not be using the cfhttp url="#base_api#" method="post"... And maybe just pass everything differently?

Comment: (Edit) *UnixStamp ... it errors other wise ...* Ohh, my bad. I forgot the java method returns *milliseconds* instead of seconds. For seconds you'd have to divide by 1000, `now().getTime()/1000`. Though DST changes the offset to UTC, so you don't ever want to hard code something like +/-7 hours. 2) No, you should be sending the parameters size,type, etc... as the request body, not as type="formfield", i.e. use `<cfhttpparam type="body" value="#body#"> 3) Fix the SerializeJSON code as described above, i..e wrap the key names in quotes.

Comment: sending like this : cfhttpparam type="body" value="{"SIDE":"SELL","SIZE":79940,"PRODUCT_ID":"SHIB-USDT","TYPE":"MARKET"}"

Comment: ERRORS in CBase if I do not send the HEADER : in the <cfhttp post : cfhttpparam type="header" name="CB-ACCESS-KEY" value="#cb_key#"> 
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE" value="#cb_pass#"> 
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="CB-ACCESS-SIGN" value="#cas#"> 
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP" value="#unixstamp#"

Comment: Coinbase needs the UNIXSTAMP EPOCH TIME in 10 digits.  KuCoin needs 13 digits.  I tweaked that error using the epochconverter.  And honestly... the server time was out 3 minutes. So errored - only figured out when I looked at server time

Comment: 1) Whether a particular API expects seconds or milliseconds, you shouldn't be hard-coding the hours offset from UTC. Not unless you want the code to fail the next time DST changes :-) 2) Yes, use `cfhttpparam type="body"...` but again, the key names "Size,Product_Id...etc" should NOT be upper case.   *".... To preserve the correct case, wrap all key names in quotes i.e. SerializeJSON({ "size": "#size#", ..."*

Comment: @Merle_the_Pearl you need to debug your data and compare it with a working request. A working request should be documented by the api provider. Then, to debug, create on a dev environment of yours a simple cfml file, where you dump the complete http request data with dump(gethttprequestdata()). Then compare them. That way you may see differences, just like the ucase issue that sos already said.

Comment: Andrea - I can't find anywhere where KuCoin or Coinbase show the expected strings and results. I have found the expected strings and results for Binance.  What I have currently is producing the expected Binance result.  So I will test that soon.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that API and unfortunately their documentation is sorely lacking any concrete examples of a generated signature. However, a good starting point would be to run the NodeJS example and output the results. Then attempt to match them with CF.

If you're not running NodeJS locally, use an online tool like [JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-nodejs-online/). For testing purposes, use a static `timestamp` and a valid base54 string for the `secret`. Output the generated values at the end of the script.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var cb_access_timestamp = 1645506818.784; 
var secret = 'c2VjcmV0IHZhbHVl'; //"secret value" in plain text
// ... rest of code ...
console.log("cb_access_timestamp=", cb_access_timestamp);
console.log("secret=", secret);
console.log("requestPath=", requestPath);
console.log("body=", body);
console.log("method=", method);
console.log("body=", body);
console.log("cb_access_sign="+ cb_access_sign);
```

Next try and replicate those results in CF. Starting with the same static values

```
cb_access_timestamp = 1645506818.784; 
secret = "c2VjcmV0IHZhbHVl"; // "secret value" in plain text
requestPath = '/orders';
method = 'POST';
```

Take special care when constructing json strings. Always assume API's are case sensitive, unlike CF. Your current code produces a json string with all upper case key names, (unlike the NodeJS example). To preserve the correct case, enclose the key names in quotes.

```
// use "[" and "]" to create ordered structure 
bodyStruct = [
    "price" : "1.0",
    "size" : "1.0",
    "side" : "buy",
    "product_id" : "BTC-USD"
];
```

Also note that CF will be overly helpful and try and guess the data types of the structure values when serializing. You may need to use [setMetaData()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/serializejson.html) to force keys like `price` and `size` to be treated as strings, instead of numbers:

```
bodyStruct.setMetaData({
   "price": {type : "string"}
   , "size" : {type : "string"}
});

body = serializeJSON( bodyStruct );
```

Finally, don't get tripped up by encodings when converting the hmac value into base64. The current code passes the [HMAC()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/hmac.html) result into [ToBase64()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/tobase64.html). That produces the wrong result because ToBase64() can only convert plain strings (ascii, utf8, etc..) and HMAC() returns a hexadecimal encoded string. Instead use [BinaryDecode()](https://cfdocs.org/binarydecode) and [BinaryEncode()](https://cfdocs.org/binaryencode) to convert the hmac from hex to base64.

```
message = cb_access_timestamp & method & requestPath & body;
key = secret.binaryDecode("base64");
hmacHex = hmac( message, key, "HMACSHA256");
cb_access_sign = binaryEncode(hmacHex.binaryDecode("hex"), "base64");
```

If you output the CF results, they should match those from the NodeJS example.

```
// Results
writeDump({
   "cb_access_timestamp":  cb_access_timestamp
   , "secret" : secret
   , "requestPath" :  requestPath
   , "body" : body
   , "method" : method
   , "body" : body
   , "cb_access_sign" : cb_access_sign
});
```

**NodeJS Results:**

```
cb_access_timestamp = 1645506818.784
secret = c2VjcmV0IHZhbHVl
requestPath = /orders
body = {"price":"1.0","size":"1.0","side":"buy","product_id":"BTC-USD"}
method = POST
body = {"price":"1.0","size":"1.0","side":"buy","product_id":"BTC-USD"}
cb_access_sign = neoPZ9ZKzQKoPGCmOuUVRY9v1NOpADQlOF+TZi2W8Qc=
```

**CF Results:**

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| body | {"price":"1.0","size":"1.0","side":"buy","product_id":"BTC-USD"} |
| cb_access_sign | neoPZ9ZKzQKoPGCmOuUVRY9v1NOpADQlOF+TZi2W8Qc= |
| cb_access_timestamp | 1645506818.784 |
| method | POST |
| requestPath | /orders |
| secret | c2VjcmV0IHZhbHVl |

If the results match, update the `timestamp` and `secret` and try passing the request parameters (size, type, product_id, side) in the request `body`, not separately as `type="formfield"`

```
cfhttp(url="#base_api#", method="post", result="result", charset="utf-8") {
   cfhttpparam( type="header", name="CB-ACCESS-KEY", value="#cb_access_key#");
   cfhttpparam( type="header", name="CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE", value="#cb_access_passphrase#");
   cfhttpparam( type="header", name="CB-ACCESS-SIGN", value="#cb_access_sign#"); 
   cfhttpparam( type="header", name="CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP", value="#cb_access_timestamp#");
   cfhttpparam( type="header", name="Content-Type", value="application/json");

   cfhttpparam( type="body", value="#body#");
}
```

Comment: If the problem is solved, you should close out the thread.